# Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera removes hash value from returnUrl

Tags: model-view-controller, hash, authorization, returnurl

I want to keep hash value in returnURL when user is sent to LogOn controller, but IE7-9/Safari/Opera removes it.

For example, I try this URL

http://localhost:18314/#&t={DA3DB617-F9A3-4668-93E6-BBB2E37B928F}

User is not authorized and sent to LogOn controller. I get just this in IE7-9, Safari, Opera:

http://localhost:18314/Login/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f

But in FireFox and Chrome:

http://localhost:18314/Login/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f#&t={DA3DB617-F9A3-4668-93E6-BBB2E37B928F}

Why and how to fix?!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the hash using %23

so this:

```
?ReturnUrl=%2fFolder1#Hash
```

becomes:

```
?ReturnUrl=%2fFolder1%23Hash
```

Tested in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after hash is not sent to server.
Good thing is that you can share cookies between your client code and server code.
I had same problem and ended up to add my hash value into one cookie

```
// Note that I am using 3rd part library for cookies
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var cookieKey = "MYHASH";
        $.removeCookie(cookieKey);
        $.cookie(cookieKey, window.location.hash, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    })
</script>
```

Later, when I am handling connected user in my controller value Request.Cookies["MYHASH"];
will give me hash value so I can redirect user. I am sure with some modifications this can help you solve the problem.